# Socket : no data on recv()

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I have an outside equipment that is suppose to send datas every second to my program computer (under linux). The documentation of this equipment says :
*Ethernet interface with a fixed IP address of 192.168.0.40
The UDP ports used for the Ethernet interface is 4230
Destination : 192.168.0.20*

So i tried to write the simpliest possible program to read these datas. My linux machine IP is set to 192.168.0.20 :

```
#define PORT 4230   
#define BUFSIZE 72 
struct sockaddr_in myaddr; /* our address */ 
struct sockaddr_in remaddr; /* remote address */ 
socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(remaddr); /* length of addresses */ 
int recvlen; /* # bytes received */ 
int fd; /* our socket */ 
unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* receive buffer */

/* create a UDP socket */ 
if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) 
{ perror("cannot create socket\n"); return 0; } /* bind the socket to any valid IP address and a specific port */ 

 memset((char *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(myaddr)); 
 myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
 myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
 myaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

 if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)) < 0) 
 { perror("bind failed"); return 0; } 

 /* now loop, receiving data and printing what we received */ 
 for (;;) 
{ 
    printf("waiting on port %d\n", PORT); 
    recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen); 
    printf("received %d bytes\n", recvlen); 
    if (recvlen > 0) 
    {
    buf[recvlen] = 0; 
    printf("received message: \"%s\"\n", buf); 
    } 
}
```

But i'm blocked at recvfrom(), never receiving datas ... What i'm doing wrong ? I tried to change INADDR_ANY to the right IP but still the same ...

Thank you.

**EDIT/UPDATE :** Using wireshark I have more information about the UDP packet from the outside equipment :
Source 192.168.0.40    Destination 192.168.0.20
Source port 4230       Dest port 2430
Maybe i need to precise the dest port on the code ? But i don't know where and how to do this ...

Comment: How do you send data to this program you show?

Comment: Also note that you have an off-by-one error in your code. If `recvfrom` fills the whole buffer and returns a value equal to `BUFSIZE`, then `buf[recvlen] = 0` will write out of bounds of your array. You should also handle errors returned by `recvfrom`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You're right for the recvfrom error. Will do it.
I don't send data, i just want to receive datas from the outside equipment for now. I have no control over the outside equipment. Do not hesitate if i'm not clear ...

Comment: Sockets are created *blocking* by default. That means attempting to receive data (with e.g. `recvfrom`) will *block* and not return until there actually is data that have been received. If you don't send any data to your socket, then `recvfrom` will wait indefinitely.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude agree, which means the problem comes from the outside equipment that does not send any data and not my program ?

Comment: This program should work fine, the problem is external (sending program, routers, bad networks dropping packets, firewalls, etc.).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "*then `recvfrom` will wait indefinitely*" - or unless you use `select()` or `SO_RCVTIMEO` to specify a timeout before reading

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Using wireshark I have more information about the UDP packet from the outside equipment : Source 192.168.0.40 Destination 192.168.0.20 Source port 4230 Dest port 2430 Maybe i need to precise the dest port on the code ? But i don't know where and how to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

The packet is destined for port `2430`, but your program is waiting for input on port `4230` (set with the `PORT` macro in your code).

The port should be the port you want input to be received on, not the source port on the other end of the communication.

So change the `PORT` macro to be `2430`.